# is there a fiddle for SharePoint CSOM/JSOM

Tags: 2013, csom, 2016

I want to check out the CSOM scripts that I see on SO

We have jsfiddle, codepen etc where we can check the JS and HTML related stuffs.

Do we have a similar one for checking CSOM snippets?  a sharepoint site where we can check these CSOM snippets and probably save some of our most used ones?

Answer (score 2):

You can only use JSOM in pages hosted in SharePoint. So, while you could share the code in a site like JSFiddle, you wouldn't be able to execute it.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I understand that CSOM requires SharePoint. so, do we have a site where we can check CSOM snippets and probably save some most used ones as well?

Comment: I'm not aware of any site like that. The closest alternative I'm aware of is Complete basic operations using JavaScript library code in SharePoint 2013 on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx

Comment: If you have a Pluralsight subscription, I would also suggest my course on SharePoint Client Object Model and REST API development: http://ow.ly/bdwc309T92U